# Syntax for a hyphenated html tag's attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails tag, what is the syntax for a hyphenated attribute? For example `data-something: "1234"` is not valid syntax.

```
<%= link_to "foo", "/bar", class: "myClass", id: "myID", data-something: "1234" %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `hyphenated attribute`?

Comment: Never mind.You got the valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to "foo", "/bar", class: "myClass", id: "myID", data: { something: "1234"} %>
```

Comment: Thanks Mandeep, this will work for the data attribute, but in general is there a way to escape the hypthen? For example in the data has if you have something like "my-attribute" then `{ my-attribute: "124" }` is not valid

Comment: @DonnyP for that you need to do data: {my_attribute: "124"} and it will automatically get converted into data-my-attribute

Answer (score 2):

There is already an answer but in general to use "hyphenated attributes" (not sure if that is the scientific term though), is just to wrap it like this...

```
<%= link_to "foo", "/bar", "data-something" => "1234" %>
```